# rails 4 nested form, 1 model dont associate id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, model-associations

I have an order form and when an order is created, a new customer is created as well. For this I have the following models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders 
    has_many :subscriptions, through: orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :subscriptions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
end

class Subscription< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :customer
end
```

On my order page I have this form:

```
= simple_form_for(@order) do |f|
    = render 'order_fields', f: f 
    = f.simple_fields_for :subscriptions do |subscription| 
        = render 'subscription_fields', subscription: subscription
    = f.simple_fields_for :customer do |customer| 
        = render 'customer_fields', customer: customer 
    = f.button :submit
```

In my OrderController I have:

```
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.build_customer
    @order.subscriptions.build
end

def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    if @order.save       
        (.... etc ...)
end

private
    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(
            :amount,
            customer_attributes: [ :id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation], 
            subscriptions_attributes: [ :id, :product_id, :customer_id])
    end
```

Almost everything goes well: 
    - User is created 
    - Order is created and has customer_id = User.id
    - Subscription is created and has order_id = Order.id

But somehow it wont associate the subscription to the customer :( 
I keep having ***Subscription.customer_id = nil***

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Is there something wrong in the models? or in the controllers?  I have no idea anymore where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships are set up a little different. Instead of creating a `customer_id` field on Subscription, I'd expect you'd just have a `has_one :customer, through: :order`.

If you do this you won't have need for a `customer_id` attribute on your Subscription model anymore. And if you want the id of the customer from the world-view of a subscription you'd call `subscription.customer.id`.

You may also want to add `inverse_of` designations for your relationships in your models (always a good practice to minimize reloading of models from the database).

So, in total, I'd recommend:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :customer
  has_many :subscriptions, through: orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :orders
  has_many :subscriptions, inverse_of: :order

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
end

class Subscription< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :subscriptions
  has_one :customer, through: :order # THIS IS THE KEY CHANGE
end
```

Oh, and then you can remove the `customer_id` from the permitted attributes for `subscriptions_attributes`.

**UPDATE**

Given that Subscription#customer_id is meant to be disjointed from the Customer -> Order -> Subscription relationship... Ignore the above (except for perhaps the `inverse_of` stuff) and... You should be able to do:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions, through: :orders, after_add: :cache_customer_id

  private

  def cache_customer_id(subscription)
    subscription.update_column(:customer_id, self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you pdobb. At one point it is working and can get the customer.subscriptions. But this way gives me problems if I want to to move the subscription to another customer (which should be possible) My idea was when the subscription has a customer reference, I can easy change the customer_id to move the subscription to another customer. Now I should move the order to another customer (or not?). That would not be right because the order should stay associated to the original customer.

Comment: I understand. In that case, you may be able to use the `after_add` callback when adding a subscription to a customer that would set the customer_id on the subscription object. I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks for the second try. :) I tried the update, but it also does not add the customer_id into the subscription model. And if it should work, this means that on every "Customer.create" the subscription model is updated and I need to be flexible so that an Admin can create a new Customer without an order or subscription. So basically what I need is a function that adds the customer_id after a Order.create only. I tried the after_add in the order.model (and changed the self.id into self.customer.id) but that gives the error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).

Comment: Then it sounds like you'll need to do it in this particular controller action instead. After creating the subscriptions loop through them and update the customer_id column real quick. Using `update_column` you won't have much chance of not saving them. I would say you could do this as part of the form but you can't since the customers don't have ids yet.

Comment: I also think it should go from the order.controller. But I can't figure out how. Something after : if Order.save --> update the subscriptions column customer_id.

Comment: `@order.subscriptions.each { |subscription| subscription.update_column(:customer_id, customer.id }`. Given you have the current customer in a local variable called `customer`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks pdobb! I got it working now with adding in the order.controller:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    if @order.save       
       @order.subscriptions.each { subscription| subscription.update_column(:customer_id, @order.customer.id) }
end
```